# paging results with keeping track of current page

Tags: angularjs

I'm displaying a paginated search results in the following format.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

using

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <span ng-click="next($index)">{{$index + 1}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm supposed to make `currentPage` as non-clickable visually using CSS, I wonder how it can be done through angular by adding or removing classes at runtime using click events. I'm simulating how google search results paging area is displayed.

```
.link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.no-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add ng-class to your markup

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <span ng-class="{'link':currentPage !== $index, 'no-link': currentPage === $index}" ng-click="next($index)">{{$index + 1}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in your next function at the top of the function add

```
if ($scope.currentPage === index) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping a `currentPage` variable on your `$scope`, and `$scope.currentPage` is being updated reliably in your `$scope.next()` function, what you can do is add an `ng-class` directive on your span:

`<span ng-click="next($index)" ng-class="{ 'link' : currentPage !== $index, 'no-link' : currentPage === $index }">{{$index + 1}}</span>`

Effectively, what we're doing is we're passing `ng-class` an object map of the form `map['cssClass'] = /* some angular expression */` If the angular expression corresponding to the CSS class is truthy, then the class will be added to the HTML element, otherwise it will be omitted.

So in your example, the 'link' class will only be added to a span if the `$index` of the page is not the page we are currently viewing (i.e. it is not `$scope.currentPage`).